# Detect a click on a specific x and y coordinates from an imageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, coordinates, detect

I have an image in my desktop and I have opened that image using Paint app and got specific location with x and y pixels for example: **374,207 px**
[image]
but when I add the image to my android app and use for example touched coordinates they are not the same? I get different values when I click on the same location in the imageView the resulting location is much higher number than in my PC.

I have been going on on this issue for about three days now I need your help.

I have tried different solution on the web for example trying to invert the touched position to get pixel values as in this example here:
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/10/get-touched-pixel-color-of-scaled.html?m=1

But again not the same x and y coordinates I get **X:592 Y:496**
[image]

Here is my code for the android app:

```
    View.OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener
            = new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            float[] eventXY = new float[] {eventX, eventY};

            Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
            ((ImageView)view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

            invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
            int x = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[0]);
            int y = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[1]);


            Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgDrawable).getBitmap();


            //Limit x, y range within bitmap
            if(x < 0){
                x = 0;
            }else if(x > bitmap.getWidth()-1){
                x = bitmap.getWidth()-1;
            }

            if(y < 0){
                y = 0;
            }else if(y > bitmap.getHeight()-1){
                y = bitmap.getHeight()-1;
            }
            
            Log.d(TAG,"X:"+x+" Y:"+y);
            return true;
        }};
```

Edit: seems like it has to do with scaling up the image but now the question is How do I map the scaled image with x and y values  I have in my database?

Comment: The `motionEvent` x/y are in view coordinates and would need to be transformed (mapped) to image coordinates.  To do this use the original image dimensions (from which you derived the desired target point) and divide by view dimensions to get a scale factor for both width and height.  Note this would change on screen rotation and other configuration changes.

Comment: @Computable Thank you for your reply, but could you please provide me with an example or a link. I have tried to figure out what you mean and did few experiments but still stuck at detecting if the user has clicked on the unscaled  version of the bitmap while actually clicking on the scaled version.

Comment: Assuming you know original dimensions (from database?) and are OK with using `wrap_content` on view then using (for width as example): `int w = v.getWidth(); float tw = event.getX(); float ratioVw = (tw / w); int origTouchX = (int) (ratioVw * (origW));`  (origW is original width).

Comment: @Computable Thanks man works! I really appreciate it and hoped that you posted it as answer so I can upvote it and mark it. Thanks again you save my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving comment to answer.

Assuming you know original dimensions (from database?) and are OK with using **wrap_content** on view then using (for width as example):

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    // get actual width of view on screen (pixels)
    int w = v.getWidth(); 

    // x coordinate in view's coordinate space
    float tw = event.getX(); 

    // ratio between x coordinate and view width
    float ratioVw = (tw / w); 

    // apply same ratio to original image width.
    int origTouchX = (int) (ratioVw * (origW)); //(origW is original width).

    return true;
}
```

Repeat for height (y).